# Adding a datetime column in pandas dataframe from minute values

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, strptime

I have a data frame where there is `time` columns having minutes from `0-1339`  meaning 1440 minutes of a day. I want to add a column `datetime` representing the day `2021-3-21` including hh amd mm like this `1980-03-01 11:00` I tried following code

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
date = datetime.date(2021, 3, 21)
days = date - datetime.date(1900, 1, 1)
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],format='%H:%M:%S:%f') +  pd.to_timedelta(days, unit='d')
```

But the error seems like `descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'`
Is there any other way to solve this problem or fixing this code? Please help to figure this out.

```
>>df
time
0
1
2
3
..
1339
```

I want to convert this minutes to particular format `1980-03-01 11:00` where I will use the date `2021-3-21` and convert the minutes to`hhmm` part. The dataframe will look like.

```
>df
datetime               time
2021-3-21 00:00         0
2021-3-21 00:01         1
2021-3-21 00:02         2
...
```

How can I format my data in this way?

Comment: What import did you use ?Try `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: I'm unclear on what the dataframe column looks like. You say it's a number `0-1339` but you try to parse it via `pd.to_datetime(df['time'],format='%H:%M:%S:%f')` that format string would not work. Can you include a sample of `df`?

Comment: I tried it. But it doesnt work.Same error. I edited the question mentioning the import.

Comment: @Henry edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try with [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) instead to get the duration in minutes from `time` then add a [`TimeStamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html):

```
df['datetime'] = (
        pd.Timestamp('2021-3-21') + pd.to_timedelta(df['time'], unit='m')
)
```

`df.head()`:

```
      time            datetime
0        0 2021-03-21 00:00:00
1        1 2021-03-21 00:01:00
2        2 2021-03-21 00:02:00
3        3 2021-03-21 00:03:00
4        4 2021-03-21 00:04:00
```

---

Complete Working Example with Sample Data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': np.arange(0, 1440)})

df['datetime'] = (
        pd.Timestamp('2021-3-21') + pd.to_timedelta(df['time'], unit='m')
)
print(df)
```